# Which FPGA with audio input

Tags: audio, input, fpga

I am searching a FPGA with an audio input. Unfortunately the cheapest I can find is this one for about 500$:

https://digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,719,1476&Prod=NEXYS-VIDEO

Does anybody know a cheaper one with an audio input?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Have you looked here? https://www.joelw.id.au/FPGA/CheapFPGADevelopmentBoards

Comment: Do you need a 7-Series FPGA for the Vivado tool chain or can it also be an old FPGA for ISE tool chain? If so, there is the Atlys board (Spartan-6 LX45 -> 230 $ (academic price) https://digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,400,836&Prod=ATLYS

Comment: Just a thought, have you looked into a separate A/D converter? No need to pay for one built into the FPGA...